# php data query returns full database text - limit to 40 characters on news snippet

Tags: php, xhtml, mysqli

I'm building a new site for a client and on the index page there is a latest news div tag.
I need to limit the info in the text box to 50 characters, and have tried the mysql `left()` function aswell as `maxlength` in php. I'm not getting the results i'm looking for.

```
<div class="sidebar">
      <h3>Latest News</h3>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <input name="news_title" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_getNews['news_title']; ?>" size="30" maxlength="30"><br />
      <textarea name="news_details" cols="25" rows="10" maxlenght="100"><?php echo $row_getNews['news_details']; $str50 = substr($mystring, 0, 50); ?></textarea>
      <br />
      <input name="news_user" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_getNews['news_user']; ?>" size="30" maxlength="30">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

assigning `$str50` doesn't make sense:

```
<textarea name="news_details" cols="25" rows="10" maxlenght="100"><?php echo $row_getNews['news_details']; $str50 = substr($mystring, 0, 50); ?></textarea>
```

one way is to just echo the first 50 characters:

```
<textarea name="news_details" cols="25" rows="10" maxlenght="100"><?php=substr($row_getNews['news_details'],0,50)?></textarea>
```